# What is defaulting this Collectors.toList to expect a List of Object?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

We are working on asyncing some calls using @Async annotation and CompletableFutures in Java. We have a number of Pojo's that we are creating objects for in our async call, but when trying to Collect the results to a List, Eclipse is wanting me to change the list of our Pojo to a list of Objects, and I'm not understanding if it's the CompletableFuture that is defaulting the response from the stream.

```
List<Pojo1> crudResponse = null;
List<Pojo1> listOfIterations =  new ArrayList<>();

//populates object with multiple entries in list
listOfIteration = populateIterationObject(param);

crudResponse = listOfIterations.stream()
    .map(str -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return async.hitCrud(str);
            }catch(RequestProcessingException e){
                log.error(e);
            }
            return function;
        }))
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

//async class
    public CompletableFuture<Pojo1> hitCrud(Pojo1 iteration) throws RequestProcessingException {

        try {
            String response;
            Pojo1 pojoResponse;
            response = connectToCrud(iteration);

            if(response != null) {
                pojoResponse.add(response);
            }                       
        }catch(Exception ex){
            log.error(ex);
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(pojoResponse);
    }
```

I hit the method to return an object of Pojo1, yet when I try to create a list using Collectors.toList() it's expecting me to have a List of `<Object>` which I can work with, but takes more coding to pull out and cast each response I get back from the async call.

Is this the CompletableFuture that is defaulting to Object? If so, is it possible to default that to the type of Pojo1 ?

Edit: 
error I am seeing in the IDE :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Pojo1>
```

Comment: No, it's the editor getting confused and not being able to infer the type. They do that sometimes.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you *do* have some type-safety issues, but it's difficult to be sure because of the incompleteness of your example.  I've been able to dummy up most of the missing bits, but what is the type of `function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is inferring a different type bound than you want because your code is wrong.  Given

> ```
> //async class
> public CompletableFuture<Pojo1> hitCrud(Pojo1 iteration) // ...
> ```

and

> ```
> List<Pojo1> crudResponse = null;
> List<Pojo1> listOfIterations =  new ArrayList<>();
> ```

..., let's analyze this stream expression:

> ```
> crudResponse = listOfIterations.stream()
>     .map(str -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
>         try {
>             return async.hitCrud(str);
>             }catch(RequestProcessingException e){
>                 log.error(e);
>             }
>             return function;
>         }))
>         .map(CompletableFuture::join)
>         .collect(Collectors.toList());
> ```

- `listOfIterations.stream()` produces a `Stream<Pojo1>`
- the type parameter of the first `map()` method invocation must be inferred from the argument, as the return type of the outer lambda.
- the return type of the outer lambda must itself be inferred from that of the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` invocation, ...
- which is itself the return type of the inner lambda.  So what is that return type?

  - well, the inner lambda can return the result of invoking `async.hitCrud(str)`, a `CompletableFuture<Pojo1>`,
  - or it can return `function`, whatever its type is.
  - the inferred type will be the nearest common ancestor of those two types, in all likelihood either `CompletableFuture<Pojo1>` or `Object`.  Given the error message, it is presumably `Object`.
- So you have mapped to a `Stream<CompletableFuture<Object>>`, thus the next mapping yields a `Stream<Object>`
- Collecting that to a List gives you a `List<Object>`, not a `List<Pojo1>`.

**That is not merely a cosmetic problem**: the list may genuinely contain objects that are not `Pojo1`s.

To see that, consider how the analysis would change if `function` had type `CompletableFuture<Pojo1>`, as does `hitCrud()`'s return value.  Then the return type of the inner lambda would be `CompletableFuture<Pojo1>`, but that would make the return type of the *outer* lambda `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Pojo1>>`, ultimately giving you a `List<CompletableFuture<Pojo1>>`, which still is not what you want.  If that is in fact your case then you can solve the problem by eliminating the outer lambda so that you map `str` using only the inner one:

```
crudResponse = listOfIterations.stream()
    .map(str -> {
            try {
                return async.hitCrud(str);
            } catch(RequestProcessingException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
            return function;
        })
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```